# Is there any way to solve this math problem without additional variables?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, pseudocode, flowchart

So I have to realize this type of algorithm:

[image: P(x):=\prod_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{x^i}]

`i` starts from `0` with the step of `1` and there has to be `n` iterations.
Input is `x` and `n`. Output is `P` which is the product of this formula. So, is there any way to solve it without additional variables?

```
int main() {

    int x, exp = 1, n, i, o;
    float p = 1;

    printf("Input value of x: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    printf("Input value of n: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
          if (i % 2 == 0)
              o = -1;
          else
              o = 1;
          exp = exp * x;
          p = p * ((-1*(float)o) / exp);    
    }
    printf("Requested number is: %f\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use this [LaTex website](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) to make your formulas readable.

Comment: Why are additional variables an issue?

Comment: One optimization could be to do it backwards, and use `n` as your iterator, so start at `n-1` and decrement that until you reach 0. Other than that, it really depends on if you can use `pow` or something like it.

Comment: You made `o` more complicated then it need be by using `o` with `* -1` which contradicts your `if/else` desicion. You can get rid of `o` because `(i & 1) * 2 - 1` will be `1` or `-1` adjust if it's the inverse. Also, please work in `double` unless you have a very good reason why you can't.

Comment: Seems like the equation is `1 * (-1/x) * (1/x^2) * ...` Is that right?

Comment: ...In that case you can remove the `o` and put `exp = -exp * x;`

Comment: Try to use arithmetic progression for numerator and denumerator.

Comment: Trivial to do by making a recursive function (which is essentially using the stack as anonymous temporary variables).

Comment: Sorry the comment before meant to say divisor, not dividend. The dividend (1 or -1) can also be calculated with n, but it's a bit tricky, observe the cycle (sign changes every 2nd i, when (-1)^i is -1), so the cycle has length 4, so `(n-1) % 4` can be used to decide if it is -1 or 1, the rest you should be able to figure out yourself.

Comment: @FilipJurgec: where does this problem come from? Are you sure you need to compute the product and not the sum of these terms?

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, its about product. It may be strange, but it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n = 5;

int x = 20;

float result = pow(-1.0/x, n*(n-1)/2);
```

**result = 9.76563e-14**

**result = -3.05176e-20 for n=6 and x= 20**

Use [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) for numerator and denumerator.

[image]
Where Z is sum of arithmetic progression from 1 to n-1 with common difference equal 1.

Comment: Pretty sure, as mentioned in my last comment, that the dividend has to be decided with `n % 4` because the sign changes every 2nd i, not on each i.

Comment: We don't need to count even powers. We need to count if sum of odd powers odd or even.

Comment: Ok see: 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1... is the sequence, the first 1 marks n = 1 because we only go to n-1. So n = 3 should be -1, your formula gives 1... correct would be `(n-1) % 4 < 2 ? 1 : -1`

Comment: @maraca I verified my results for n=5 and x=20 (n=6 and x=20) with Filip Jurgec program. They are the same.

Comment: Sorry his program seems to be correct but is written very strangely. Still interested in n = 3, should be negative.

Comment: @maraca. I made an update. For n=3 -> (-1)^(1+2)=(-1)^3=-1

Comment: Yes this works too, because every 2nd number is odd and changes the power from odd to even or even to odd. It's basically the same as my %4 formula. If you do it like that I would use a variable for the sum. Anyway +1 nice graphic.

Comment: We can apply, make this generic, the same power calculation to -1 as we do for x. It is the sum of arithmetic progression. if n=3 this sum equals to 3*(3-1)/2=3

Comment: Yes it is correct, but you could do pow(-1/x, ...) only calculate the power once. Exactly like your graphic.

Comment: pow(-1/x, ...)  gives always 0, so I split it as you see in my updated answer.

Comment: You need to use -1.0 or cast the 1 or the x has to be float or double, otherwise integer division is used.

Comment: Or you can use `float result = pow(-x, -n*(n-1)/2);`

Comment: that was helpful, ty very much guys

Comment: i just made it without pow, cause we are not allowed to use any external function:           float result = 1;
 for (i = 1; i <= n * (n - 1) / 2; i++) {
  result = result * (-1 / (float)x);
 }

Comment: @chqrlie: I just saw that upper limit goes all the way to n, not to n-1, so the sum of exponents (and upper limit as well) is n×(n+1)/2. So for looks like this: for (i = 1; i <= n * (n + 1) / 2; i++). You can read original formula on my answer of this post.

Answer (score 1):

The series you are trying to compute seems incorrect. It is more likely to be a sum than a product as the product can be simplified to **(-x)<sup>-(n*(n+1))/2</sup>**, which rapidly converges toward **0** for x > 1, oscillates between 1 and -1 for x = 1 and diverges for x < 1.

The product can be computed without any other local variables:

```
printf("Requested number is: %f\n", pow(-x, -n * (n + 1) / 2));
```

To compute the sum instead of the product, which is the Taylor series for **1 / (1 + x)**, the code needs some changes, and indeed can use fewer variables:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    double x, term, sum;

    printf("Input value of x: ");
    if (scanf_s("%lf", &x) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("Input value of n: ");
    if (scanf_s("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    sum = term = 1.0;
    while (n --> 0)
        sum += term /= -x;

    printf("Requested number is: %f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not sum, it is product.

Comment: @yW0K5o: I'm afraid there is no confirmation from the OP about that. I amended the answer for the product too, a much simpler question, no loop needed.

Comment: @yW0K5o: the product is meaningless, but the sum is a well known Taylor series.

Comment: this is how his mathematical formula is written.

Comment: **Output is P which is the product of this formula**

Comment: @yW0K5o: I have seen  that and he does mention *product* in the question, but I suspect he misread the problem statement, His question about the number of local variables is weird, he has not answered any question nor written any comment, how can you be so sure about anything?

Answer (score 0):

[Original formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkIJF.png)

So this is the original formula. It is about product, not sum. Thank you guys very much for your effort and answers. I wanted to solve this problem with no additional variables because professor always warns us about memory and cpu usage.